# PHP - Concatenation of chr function returns an image

Tags: php, chr

I have stumbled upon this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php). It's about `chr` function in PHP. There is an example in this link that I can't understand.

```
declare(encoding='UTF-8');
$str = chr(240) . chr(159) . chr(144) . chr(152);
echo $str;
```

This code gives "an elephant image" as an answer. I don't understand how this code above works? Are there any explanation about how the concatenation of `chr` works?

I will give more examples about this. I change the number from the last `chr`.

```
echo chr(240) . chr(159) . chr(144) . chr(154); // return a shell logo
echo chr(240) . chr(159) . chr(144) . chr(156); // return an ant logo
echo chr(240) . chr(159) . chr(144) . chr(158); // return a ladybug logo
echo chr(240) . chr(159) . chr(144) . chr(160); // return a fish logo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers written in hex are `0xF0` `0x9F` `0x90` `0x98`. This is the UTF-8 code for an elephant, see for example [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F418).

Comment: In the link that you provide, I notice that UTF-16 code for an elephant is `0xD83D 0xDC18`. Does these hexadecimal comes from the multiplication of four UTF-8 code?

Comment: No, it's a bit more complicated. In UTF-8, you can have between 1 to 4 bytes per symbol. If the highest bit of the first byte is set, a second byte follows, similar for second and third. UTF-16 is a different encoding with similar rules, but starting with two bytes. For details read for example [the articles on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). In the end, the encoded value is the unicode code point U+1F418.